# Copy/Paste - From Mac to Virtual box

Tags: macos, virtualbox

I am working on a document on mac (osx 10.9) and I have a virual machine running windows 7 - the issue is I dont know how to enable it so I can copy text from the word document in mac to the word document or application in the virtual box.

I have guest editions installed and enabled ...

How does one enable copy and paste from host to client?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Check if the "Shared Clipboard" feature is disabled. It should be somewhere around Settings > General > Advanced. You can set it to bidirectional or any other setting you need.

Comment: Read this to so you can use the same keys to copy/paste from Host to Guest. https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=63567

Comment: In my case, I also need to execute this `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms` and restart my virtual box.

Comment: `unable to locate package virtualbox-guest-dkms`. I googled the package name and discovered many people saying not to install it.

Answer (score 43):

I'm using a Windows VM on a Mac OS host. I had to install the Guest Additions onto the actual VM so that it knows how to communicate with the host machine. Here's what I did:

- launch the Windows 10 VM
- In the top menu go to Device -> Insert Guest Additions CD image
- On the Windows VM go to Explorer, then look for the drive that represents the newly "inserted" CD
- Once there, run VBoxWindowsAdditions.exe as administrator and install
- Enable Clipboard and Drag&Drop under either VM settings or the Devices menu

[This article](https://4sysops.com/archives/virtualbox-copy-and-paste-not-working/) has helped me understand how it works.

Comment: The best explanation on internet. Thank you @aexl

Comment: This in addition with this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63105054/316700

Comment: I'm on a unix guest, not windows, but these instructions are the same. I know that because I have found them all over the place on the internet. They do not work.

Answer (score 17):

Copy from MAC with  <kbd>⌘</kbd>  +  <kbd>C</kbd>  and
Paste to VirtualBox with  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>⇧</kbd>  +  <kbd>V</kbd>

Vice versa  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>⇧</kbd>  +  <kbd>C</kbd>  in VirtualBox and  <kbd>⌘</kbd>  +  <kbd>V</kbd>  on MAC would also work! ;)

Comment: You made my day

Comment: This in addition with this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50837371/316700

Comment: Just tried it. These key combos do not work. Neither do the key combos I set up in the keyboard settings.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the help menu in VirtualBox (and other applications) to very easily to find what you need:

[image]

I prefer `bidirectional` setting so I can copy and paste back and forth between systems

Comment: Downvoting for not providing a solution. The help included with VirtualBox contains exactly one instance of the word "paste" and it has nothing to do with copying and pasting between host and guest.

Answer (score 3):

In machine display, you can do follow, 100% work:

1. Devices -> Drag and Drop -> Bidirectional
2. Devices -> Insert Guest Additions CD images, then install it.

Comment: I have done both of those. Works 0%. Downvoted.

Answer (score 3):

You will want to turn Shared Keyboard on in the devices menu in VirtualBox. Also, in MacOS you will need to go to System Preferences > Security and Privacy > and check VirtualBox under Input Monitoring and Accessibility.

Comment: There is no "Shared Keyboard" in the devices menu in VirtualBox. Also, there is no "Input Monitoring" in my MacBook Pro's Security and Privacy settings. I do have VirtualBox checked off under Accessibility. I still cannot copy and paste between host and guest.

Answer (score 1):

The above solution did not work for me.

**This worked for me.**

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#additions-windows

1. Open Virtualbox.app (show contents) in Applications, look under MacOS folder and copy this file VBoxGuestAdditions.iso to desktop
2. Point your virtugal optical disc to this iso and your ubuntu will ask to install.

Install it and copy and paste will work from your mac to ubuntu virtual box termninal.

Comment: Done. This does not work for me and many other people.

Answer (score 1):

Bidirectional Clipboard requires the Guest Additions. To get Guest Additions to work I had to use the following steps.

- **Enable Clipboard**

  - Settings > General > Advanced

    - Shared Clipboard > Bidirectional
    - (Note, Host -> Guest works by default but Bidirectional requires the Guest Additions)
- **Add guest additions**

  - Add optical drive

    - VirtualBox > Settings > Storage

      - On the IDE controller click the "Add new storage attachment" > Optical > **Leave Empty**
      - (Do not select the VBoxGuestAdditions.iso image as the installers won't run as expected within the VM.)
  - Start the Machine

    - In the Devices Menu in the MacOS bar, select Insert Guest Additions CD Image...
    - Follow prompts for install
  - Restart machine

Comment: Followed these instructions to the letter. Just to make sure, I also compared what I did to the instructions at https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html. These same instructions appear elsewhere on the internet and I have followed them numerous times, then when they didn't work, started over with a fresh VM and tried again. I have now been working on this for a full day. These instructions simply do not work. They are incorrect.